# automatically bind a device to a specific driver

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, hid

I would like to bind a hid device to a specific driver.

Unfortunately hid-generic somehow "steals" the binding when the device is reconnected.

I know i can unbind and bind the device by hand this way:

```
# echo ... > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/unbind 
# echo ... > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/customdriver/bind
```

But isn't there something like a priority for drivers to automatically bin a device to a driver?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think there may be a blacklist in generic hid. Check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/prevent-usbhid-from-claiming-usb-device

Comment: U can use udev rules for that. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786343/prevent-usbhid-from-autoloading-when-usb-hid-device-is-plugged-in

Comment: @OrtwinAngermeier Thanks - but you are 3 minutes too late :D (see the second entry in my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to automatically bind a device to my driver

- Adding the device to the **hid_have_special_driver** struct in hid-core.c.

  The struct looks somthing like that:

  ```
  static const struct hid_device_id hid_have_special_driver[] = {
  #if IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_HID_A4TECH)
      { HID_USB_DEVICE(USB_VENDOR_ID_A4TECH, USB_DEVICE_ID_A4TECH_WCP32PU) },
      { HID_USB_DEVICE(USB_VENDOR_ID_A4TECH, USB_DEVICE_ID_A4TECH_X5_005D) },
      { HID_USB_DEVICE(USB_VENDOR_ID_A4TECH, USB_DEVICE_ID_A4TECH_RP_649) },
  #endif
      //...
      {}
  }
  ```

  This is how it is normally done, I haven't tried it yet. You have to recompile hid-core.c (hid.ko).
- Using the bind and unbind functionality inside an **udev-rule**.

  Add a new rule to /etc/udev/rules.d/ (e.g. 99-mydriver.rules) which automatically unbinds the device from hid-generic and binds it to your driver

  Under Arch Linux x86_64:

  ```
  ACTION=="bind", KERNELS=="0005:<VENDOR_ID>:<PRODUCT_ID>.*", SUBSYSTEMS=="hid", DRIVERS=="hid-generic", \
  RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/$driver/unbind'", \
  RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/<MY_DRIVER>/bind'"
  ```

  Under Raspbian Stretch the following works for me

  ```
  ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="0005:<VENDOR_ID>:<PRODUCT_ID>.*", SUBSYSTEM=="hid", DRIVER=="hid-generic", \
  RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/unbind'", \
  RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo $kernel > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/<MY_DRIVER>/bind'"
  ```

  Replace `<VENDOR_ID>`, `<PRODUCT_ID>` and `<MY_DRIVER>` as needed

---

Further Information: http://0x0001.de/linux-driver-loading-registration-and-binding/